# Where docker-compose stored image files

Tags: docker-compose, directus

On a Linux server, I installed the CMS Directus by using docker-compose. Now I need to change the configuration.php of Directus to enable CORS. But I cannot find this configuration file. Please show me where docker-compose stored the image files or how to access them. Many thanks in advance.

- The yml & dockerfile is the same as https://github.com/directus/directus-docker

Comment: Maybe accessing the container? `sudo docker exec -ti directus bash`

Answer (score 2):

In general you should not modify a container to fit your needs, but modify the image. Why? On restart of the container, all the changes are gone. You eliminate most of the advantages of Docker containers doing that. (You could also create a new image from a running container, but I would also not recommend that, because it's hard to reproduce the state of that...)

Either create a custom image by writing a Dockerfile (you can reuse the other image). In your usecase you would ADD a file to the image.

Or you could mount a file (the configuration file) to the right folder, when running the image.

To find the right place of the file, you might either check the original Dockerfile or inspect the container by bashing into it like grovina suggested.